# Last column of JTable is getting shrunk

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

If the `JTable` is less than the panel size I want to use `AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS`.

If the table has more columns then I want to keep all the columns to the maximum width with a scrollbar.

But when I try to use the below code, the last column is getting shrunk.
I want to know if I'm missing something.

```
//Adjust columns according to max width(header,Content)
TableColumnAdjuster tca = new TableColumnAdjuster(table);
tca.adjustColumns();

//Adjust the column to max width with double click if the column is shrinked
new ResizeColumnListner(table);

JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(table,ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS , ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);  

table.getParent().addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void componentResized(final ComponentEvent e) {
        if (table.getPreferredSize().width < table.getParent().getWidth()) {
            table.setAutoResizeMode(table.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
        } else {
            table.setAutoResizeMode(table.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Post an [mre] demonstrating the problem. There is no need for the TableColumnAdjuster or ResizeColumnListener. First solve the problem without custom code. Then add in custom code to see if it still works.

Comment: For your information: There is a mistake in the code in your question. The `JScrollPane` [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#JScrollPane-java.awt.Component-int-int-) is wrong. The second parameter is the **vertical** scrollbar policy and the third parameter is the horizontal scrollbar policy.

Answer (score 1):

The table will be auto resized depending mode value. There are 5 modes:

**AUTO_RESIZE_OFF:** Don't automatically adjust the column's widths at all. Use a horizontal scrollbar to accomodate the columns when their sum exceeds the width of the Viewport. If the JTable is not enclosed in a JScrollPane this may leave parts of the table invisible.

**AUTO_RESIZE_NEXT_COLUMN:** Use just the column after the resizing column. This results in the "boundary" or divider between adjacent cells being independently adjustable.

**AUTO_RESIZE_SUBSEQUENT_COLUMNS:** Use all columns after the one being adjusted to absorb the changes. This is the default behavior.

**AUTO_RESIZE_LAST_COLUMN:** Automatically adjust the size of the last column only. If the bounds of the last column prevent the desired size from being allocated, set the width of the last column to the appropriate limit and make no further adjustments.

**AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS:** Spread the delta amongst all the columns in the JTable, including the one that is being adjusted.

From your question , it is not clear how you adding the `JScrollPane` object to the frame window's content pane. Here is an [Exploring Swing's Table Component](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=24130&seqNum=5) article to read and get understanding how everything works together.